# BXNVM0056E There was an error adding you to the public cloud

Tags: virtual-machine, ibm-cloud, public

While I'm applying VM in Bluemix Dashboard, error occurs:

> "BXNVM0056E There was an error adding you to the public cloud. Try
>   again later. If problem persists, contact support at
>   https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#ask"

[image]

Comment: Hello, could you describe when you get this error? Asking for beta VM service?

Answer (score 2):

In the last minutes I got the same error but now all is working fine.
Try again and if the issue still persist  open a support request directly from your Bluemix console using the support/help widget in the Bluemix UI (panel from the user avatar in the upper right corner) or from the Bluemix Support GetHelp form (http://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport)